# How do I change tag appearance on a pre-made Tumblr theme?

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes, tumblr-tags

I was wondering if anyone knew how to help me with changing the appearance of my tags. They look like oldschool links (underlined and blue) and it's very garish - it clashes very badly with the rest of my theme. I'm unfamiliar with CSS coding, but all instruction helps! Here's a link to my blog to see what I'm talking about: http://spanz-spectral.tumblr.com/ .

Comment: Were there tags in the original theme? Without a copy of the theme code (especially the `{block:HasTags}` block), it is impossible to tell what can/needs to be changed and how.

Comment: I added the generic tags block that I found someone else on this site recommend. How can I give you the coding? Just copy and paste it?

Comment: You could build a "minimum working example" paring the code down. Many people like to use pastebin for heavier code, though.

Answer (score 1):

I know how!
Look for {block:HasTags} in your theme HTML. Around the `<a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>` you can add HTML tags that change the layout such as font colour, font size, font style, etc.
See below for an example:

```
{block:HasTags}
       {block:Tags}
          <font size="2"> 
          <font color="#FFFFFF">
          <a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>
          </font>
          </font>
       {/block:Tags}
    {/block:HasTags}
```

I hope that helps!

Now I'm just trying to figure out how to automatically place a comma after each tag, but not when there is just one tag displayed. ;__;

Answer (score 0):

I realize this post is old but maybe you or someone googling this thread will find this helpful. I also use that theme, Munich, and use this to display my tags:

```
    {block:HasTags}
          {block:Tags}
             <i>
             <font size="2">
             <font color="#FFBC00">
             <font="Lucida Sans Unicode">
             #{Tag}
             </font>
             </font>
             </i>
          {/block:Tags}
    {/block:HasTags}
```

It's just cobbled together with the little HTML I know but it works. Just put it in every "type" of post, look for the headers that look like {block:Link}, there should be 7. Put this at the end right before the

```
    </div>
    </block:Link}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to building on what you guys already gave me (found via Google), I’ve finally gotten this to work exactly how I hoped with the Munich theme. So here’s what I did: go into *Customize* → *Edit HTML*. Select the giant chunk of code you find into a Notepad .txt file to make it easier to work with. Right, now scrolling through the top of it, you'll find a bit that says `/* GENERAL POSTS */`. Somewhere in this section, add this:

```
}

.tag a {
    color:{color:Links};
    text-decoration:none;

}

.tag a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
```

This will basically tell your theme how to handle your tags when you add them, so they don’t end up bright blue and clashing with everything. Now, scroll down and you’ll find lots of sections for formatting individual types of entries—the first one for me is `{block:Link}`, and the last is `{block:Audio}`. At the end of each of these sections, right before the `</div> {/block:Link}` you need to add this:

```
<div class="tag">
    {block:HasTags}
          {block:Tags}
             <i>
             <font size="2">
             <font color="{color:Links}">
             <font="Lucida Sans Unicode">
             #<a style="{color:Links};" href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>
             </font>
             </font>
             </i>
          {/block:Tags}
    {/block:HasTags}
</div>
```

You need to go through and add this at the bottom of each type of entry, being careful to always put it before the last `</div>` (sometimes there are two of those—put it in between them if so) and before the `{/block:Link}`.